# unable to format output

Tags: java, string

```
System.out.println("Name\tRollno\tAddress\tPercentage");
while(rs.next())
{
name=rs.getString(1);
lname=rs.getString(2);
address=rs.getString(3);
city=rs.getString(4);

    System.out.print(name+"\t\t");

  if(lname.length()<=7)
{
    System.out.print(lname+"\t\t");
}
else
    System.out.print(lname+"\t");

 if(address.length()<=7)
{
    System.out.print(address+"\t\t");
}
else
    System.out.print(address+"\t");

    System.out.println(city);
}
```

The data is not coming under the heading name address etc.
How to format it the output? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although String.format would work perfectly, I'd venture towards PrintStream.printf().
The following code would print out what you want in perfect columns. Depending on the actual values you have in your result set, you might need to change the value for the width of the columns

```
int nameWidth = 15
int rollNumberWidth = 10
int adddressWidth = 25
int percentWidth = 5
String format = "%" + nameWidth + "s"
                    + "%" + rollNumberWidth + "s"
                    + "%" + addressWidth + "s"
                    + "%" + percentWidth + "s\n";
System.out.printf(format ,"Name", "Rollno", "Address", "Percentage");
while(rs.next())
{
    name = rs.getString(1);
    lname = rs.getString(2);
    address = rs.getString(3);
    city = rs.getString(4);
    System.out.printf(format , name, lname, address, city);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would advise using the `String.format` method with `%15s` where 15 is the width of the column and can be anything you like.

Using `"\t"` is pretty dependent on how you're displaying the result, e.g. in a text editor, the width of a tab character can be anything the user chooses.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Comment: Good advice, however the link you provide is to an old version of Java.

Comment: can u give example in my question context

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29 says the same thing.